# For water, 1 mole = 18 g= 22.4 liter. How to explain?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

For water, 1 mole = 18 g= 22.4 liter. But practically, how 22.4 liter is equal to 18 g?

Comment: 22.4 liters of liquid water does not weigh 18 g. Pay attention to the phase.

Answer (score 4):

For water, 1 gram is approximately 1 mL.

22.4 L/mol is the molar volume of an ideal gas at STP.

Since water is not a gas at STP, you can't apply that.

If you had one mole substance that is a gas at STP (hydrogen, nitrogen, carbon dioxide, etc.) you could say that they occupy a volume of approximately 22.4 L.

Comment: 22.4 L/mol is for the "old" STP. The current definition of STP is 0 C and 100 kPa which has a volume of 22.7 L/mol.

Comment: Water can be a gas if it's water vapor.  22.4 L is the volume of 18 g of water vapor at 1 atm and 0 C.

Comment: Water can't exist in the gaseous state at these conditions.